# Debug executable option in Xcode Scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode6

Besides the obvious feature that is to permit the debugging of the app (most of the time using a *Debug Configuration*), why you should leave this option enabled, for example, even in *Release Configuration*?

What is the proper use of this feature?

Comment: "From what I know in the release build symbolic debug info is not emitted."  Check the build settings; they all have a Release and Debug version and it's very useful to retain the symbols for symbolicating crashes in the wild.  Also some bugs only appear when optimisation is turned on.

Comment: @trojanfoe It's correct, I removed that part

Comment: Someone please answer this question? There is no info to find about it on Google as far as I can see...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH8-SW22):

> The “Debug executable” checkbox specifies whether or not you want to run with the debugger enabled. Once running, you can use Debug > Attach to Process on a process that has been launched with debugging disabled if needed.

It seems like all this does is start your app with the debugger attached. You probably want it on.

Comment: Link is broken :/

Comment: Here's a [working link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH8-SW22).